# How to replace a specific sequence of numbers (in consecutive rows) with a different sequence

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a database and I'm a novice using python. I have been able to use numpy and pandas functions to accomplish some things but now I want to do something that may or may not be easily solvable

I have a data source that outputs 1s and 0s and I used fillna to successfully fill in the gaps in the column.

But now I want to create a new column that copies the first col then replaces the data when a specific sequence occurs.

```
#When col1 = [1, 0, 0]
#replace with [1, 1, 1]
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('HoboProbe_and_MotorState.txt') 


df['Date_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Time'])

df.set_index('Date_Time',drop=True,inplace=True) 

df.sort_index(inplace=True)


df['filled_motor'] = df['motor_state']


df['filled_motor'].fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True) 

df['filled_motor'].fillna(method='bfill',inplace=True) 

# all this above works fine, below is what I have attempted to solve the problem

df['col_Test1'] = df['filled_motor']

df['col_Test1'] = df['col_Test1'].replace([1, 0],[1, 1]) 
#this just replaced all the 1 and 0 with 1, as apposed to replacing it only when the 1, 0 sequence occures 

df['col_Test2'] = np.where((df['filled_motor']==1) & ((df['filled_motor']+1)==0), 1, df.filled_motor) 
#here I tried to say where col==1 and where col(row+1)==0 input a 1 everywhere else input col.  But this did not work either
```

I would like to know how to replace a specific sequence of rows in a col with another specific sequence.

However, as I thought more about this specific issue I wondered if it is made more difficult by some type of logic error in my thinking, where whenever a sequence of 1, 0, 0 is replaced with 1, 1, 1 it will just create a new sequence of 1, 0, 0 right after it and thus will always end up yielding a col of all 1 (as I said earlier I am def a novice and my programming logic could be way off)

Thanks

Comment: Can you give a sample of what the df['filled_motor'] column looks like?

Comment: its just a column of 0 and 1 so:
filled_motor
1
1
1
1
0
0
0
0
1
1
1
they are associated with date_time column. there will typically be about 40-100 1s followed by maybe 2000 0s then repeat

Answer (score 0):

This is really a convolution problem. Or detecting matching patterns' problem.
I created a single column `col1` with a sequence and originally this is a numeric array series.

But I converted that to a string and then simple replaced the pattern, and back to the column `c`.

You can use string functions

```
s = df.col1.astype(str).sum()
s =s.replace('100', '111')
print(s)
df['c']=list(s)
print(df)
```

---

Here is the output:

```
   col1
0     0
1     1
2     0
3     0
4     1
5     1
6     0
0111110
   col1  c
0     0  0
1     1  1
2     0  1
3     0  1
4     1  1
5     1  1
6     0  0
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea to convert the number sequence to a string. But, when I try to make it work with my database  I get an error:

ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

I am using df.to_csv to write back to CSV.  My index is set to my date_time column (I tried changing that but it didn't correct the error)